# Promote Azure build from Jenkins

Tags: azure, jenkins, azure-devops, pipeline, azure-service-hooks

I have two project1 and project2 hosted on jenkins and azure devops respectively.

1. Jenkins => project1
2. Azure Deveops =>project2

My requirement is when user trigger project1 build from jenkins manually once project1 build succeed at the same time automatically trigger project2 build which is hosted on azure.

So that end user can test both projects on there environments.

Comment: [HTTP Request](https://plugins.jenkins.io/http_request/) should be able to trigger Azure DevOps server job.

Comment: Hi there, have you got a chance to check if the answer below would meet your request?

Comment: Hi Alvin, I am creating samples to verify, Once done i will let you know

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, you may consider using [WebHook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#define-a-webhooks-resource) to trigger the pipeline in Azure DevOps.

1. Add a command like below to post WebHook payload from your Project 1 in Jenkins to the URL;

   ```
   $URL = "https://dev.azure.com/<TheDevOpsOrgName>/_apis/public/distributedtask/webhooks/<WebHookName>?api-version=6.0-preview"
   $header = @{

       'Content-Type' = 'application/json'
   }
   $Payload = @"
     {
       "parameter_from_Jenkins": "Jenkins webhook trigger",
       "parameter_name": "test"
     }
   "@
   Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $URL -Headers $header -Body $Payload | ConvertTo-Json
   ```
2. Create an incoming WebHook service connection like below;
   [image: Incoming WebHook Service Connection]
3. Add a WebHook resource into the YAML pipeline;

   ```
   trigger: none
   pool:
     vmImage: windows-latest
   resources:
     webhooks:
     - webhook: WebHookName ### Webhook alias
       connection: WebHookSvcCnn ### Incoming webhook service connection
   steps:
     - task: PowerShell@2
       inputs:
         targetType: 'inline'
         script: 'Write-Host This pipeline run is triggered by ${{ parameters.WebHookName.parameter_from_Jenkins }}'
   ```
4. Once the request is sent, the WebHook service connection will listen the incoming request and trigger the pipeline in DevOps.
   [image: Pipeline run triggered by WebHook]

Comment: Where to ADD step1 in jenkins? Trying to add inside Build=>Execute Windows batch Command